# Excel complicated intersecting cell

Tags: excel, report, intersection

I'm struggling with a report. Is there any way to do this task?

As you look at the picture there is an intersection which value I would like to know.

[image]

The problem is that it's not a single value, there are around 400 cells. So excel would need to analyze the entire sheet by "Suma" and "L. godz.pozostalych do odebrania"

What I would like to achieve:

1. I would like to get values of all  red intersections (I highlighted them only to make them visible, normally they have no color)
2. If their value is more than than 0 I would like to have them printed on the next sheet with the ID number.

Also It would be a repeated process, the sheets need to be done every month so I would like to create something that would  work for all of them.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please answer **all** of the following questions: What version of Excel?  Is `Suma` always in Column 2?  will the value you want always be the last value in that row?

Comment: Hi Ron!  My excel version is 1902 (released in 2019). Yes suma is always in column J (range J3:J1500) and yes- the value will always be the last value in that row.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me, based on your comments, that all you really need is the last numeric value in the row that contains the word `suma` in column J.  The vertical header would seem to be irrelevant (except perhaps as a marker for that column if needed).

Given that you have Excel 2019, I am assuming that you do NOT have the `FILTER` or `SEQUENCE` functions which would simplify the formulas, but the following should work:

- I selected a range that included all the data and `NAME`'d it `myRng`.

The following formula will then return the last numeric value in the row that has the word "suma":

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(INDEX(myRng, AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(INDEX(myRng,0,2)="suma")*ROW(myRng),ROWS($1:1)),0)),INDEX(myRng, AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(INDEX(myRng,0,2)="suma")*ROW(myRng),ROWS($1:1)),0)),"")
```

In the portion of the formula `INDEX(myRng,0,2)` you will need to change the `2` to reflect the column of `myRng` that represents column `J`.  *(or you could just define `myRng` to start at column `I`)*

[image]

You should be able to figure out a formula or procedure to show the relevant values on another worksheet.

Comment: @Marta Clearly it works on the example in my screenshot. Since I have no idea what you mean by *sadly it doesn't work*, I will not be able to help you except to surmise that you either did not implement what I suggested correctly; did not accurately convey your problem and the nature of your data; have malware on your computer that is interfering; have a hardware problem with your computer; etc, etc, etc.  Good Luck